# S3 sink connector configuration based on operation type of Debezium messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

We want to distinguish between messages in Kafka(which is coming from Debezium) based on operation type.
We are looking for routing messages based on operation type in Kafka.

Debezium sends different kind of operation types like r(read), u(update), delete(d), etc.

something like

- if operation = r -> send to bucket 1
- if operation = u, d -> send to bucket 2

We kind of want to segregate snapshot and delta data from Debezium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Content-Based router as in [this example](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.0/transformations/content-based-routing.html#example-basic-content-based-routing-configuration) to send the operations to different topics (this requires installing Debezium scripting, see in the same link). This will create separate topics with the messages but I don't know if you can use the same S3 sink connector to take both topics to different buckets (as [it seems](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/overview.html#limitations) that it doesn't support routing) so you might have to create a connector for each topic and configure each of them with the correct sink bucket.

Comment: this seems like a good option but we don't want to disturb the Debezium connector. We want to do changes only in S3 sink connector for now if feasible.

if we don't find any other way, we might got for your suggested approach.
thank you @eagr